# Implicit Derivative with Three Variable

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ from these equation:

$xyz-2xz+3yz-4xy=0$

How $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ can be done using manually method? Thanks... I stuck at variable whose contains 'z'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = z'$, we have: $xyz - 2xz + 3yz - 4xy = 0 \Rightarrow z(xy-2x+3y) = 4xy$. Using the product rule and differentiating both sides with respect to $x$:

$z'(xy-2x+3y) + z(y-2) = 4y \Rightarrow \dfrac{4xyz'}{z} = 4y - yz + 2z \Rightarrow z' = \dfrac{z(4y-yz+2z)}{4xy} = \dfrac{z(4y-yz+2z)}{z(xy-2x+3y)} = \dfrac{-yz+2z+4y}{3y-2x+yx}$

Comment: But, the key answer is : $\frac{-yz+2z+4y}{3y-2x+yx}$

Comment: cancels out the z? What that means?

Comment: Ok!!!! I understand now!!!! Thanks for your help!!!!